# Adjust p-value for multiple ANOVAs

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, type-i-and-ii-errors

There are similar questions to mine but either with no response or the setting is different.

In short:
I have conducted a study with 1 independent categorical variable, 5 dependent variables and 4 hypotheses (One of the hypotheses focussing on 2 dependent variables).
For each variable I have conducted an ANOVA. (And there are reasons, why I have not used the MANOVA approach). Now I am wondering about how to adjust the p-values.

My question now is:
Do I have to adjust the p-values for all ANOVAS - So I got 5 ANOVAS and I have to adjust my significance level by alpha/5 (in case I use bonferroni)?
And what about the post-hoc tests for each ANOVA? Do I have to adjust the p-values again?

Thank your very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your results are more credible if you adjust the p-values for multiple dependent variables. But with highly correlated dependent variables, Bonferroni’s correction is extremely conservative.

An alternative is to adjust the p-values by permutation or rotation testing.  Rotation testing relies on multivariate normal distribution theory and the p-values are calculated by simulations. This is implemented in the r package ffmanova (although post-hoc tests are not treated).

Below is an example with a single independent categorical variable (x) and five dependent variables stored in an ordinary data frame.

```
library(ffmanova)
z <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(45), 9, 5))
z$x <- c("A", "B", "C")
res <- ffmanova(cbind(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) ~ x, data = z, nSim = 999)
res$pRaw       # Ordinary p-values
res$pAdjusted  # Adjusted p-values
```

Increase nSim for more accurate p-values.

https://cran.r-project.org/package=ffmanova